# Is there any way to get list of arguments in Kotlin for function

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way to get list of arguments for a function in Kotlin like Javascript has arguments.

thanks

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: I want to get list of arguments, passed to a function in Kotlin. Like Javascript has a way to get arguments passed to function

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't make any more sense. Unless you're talking about some specific pattern, there's `fun someFun(list: List<Any>)`.

Comment: There's also `vararg` if that's what you're looking for, in which case you should edit and clarify that. If that's wrong too, add some code to demonstrate what you're trying to do (or at least add more explanation). Otherwise, you risk question closure.

Comment: Kotlin doesn’t have an equivalent of Javascript’s `arguments` object.

Comment: There's Kotlin reflection. I think that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct Kotlin equivalent to JavaScript's `arguments` implicit object.

However, if you really want to access arguments as a list, you can either use an actual `List` like this:

```
fun myFunc(args: List<String>) {
   // do something with the list "args"
}

// call it this way:
myFunc(listOf("a", "b", "c"))
```

Or you can use [varargs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs), which create an array implicitly for you, like this:

```
fun myFun(vararg args: String) {
    // use "args" as an Array<out String>
}

// call it this way:
myFunc("a", "b", "c")
```